# Filter index in activeAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In my activeadmin application, I need to filter the records that will appear in the index view.

For my "Group" model, the collection approach works well but for the "Item" model, it does not work and return the following error:

```
undefined method `page' for #<Array:0xc240bc4>
```

I use this code in admin/items.rb: => does not work

```
collection_action :index, :method => :get do
  # Only get the items belonging to a group owned by the current user
  scope = Group.where("owner_id = ?", current_user.id).map{|group| group.items}

  @collection = scope.page() if params[:q].blank?
  @search = scope.metasearch(clean_search_params(params[:q]))

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
    render "active_admin/resource/index"
  }
  end
end
```

In admin/groups.rb, the following works fine though (only the correct groups are displayed)

```
collection_action :index, :method => :get do
  # Only get the groups owned by the current user
  scope = Group.where("owner_id = ?", current_user.id).scoped

  @collection = scope.page() if params[:q].blank?
  @search = scope.metasearch(clean_search_params(params[:q]))

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
      render "active_admin/resource/index"
    }
  end
end
```

I cannot figure out why this is not working for the "Item" model. Any idea ?

**EDIT**

I find a workaround, only getting the items of the first groups belonging to the current_user:

```
scope = Group.where("owner_id = ?", current_user.id).first.items.scoped
```

It's ok for now because the users only have one group but this will not be suitable in a near future.

Comment: You notice the `.scoped` in your second bit of code? This enables the array to become a relational activerecord object

Comment: ActiveAdmin allows using  only ActiveRecord::Relation , when you called map, it became Array, so change your scope according to your needs.

something like 

current_user.group.items should work

Comment: @Fivell what if current_user has several groups ? current_user.groups.items will not work in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try has many :through
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Some kind of

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  belongs_to :user
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  has_many :items, :through => :groups
end
```

That will allow you to do next scope

```
 current_user.items
```

in your controller

Answer (score 0):

`admin/items.rb`

`scope = Group.where("owner_id = ?", current_user.id).map{|group| group.items}`

`admin/groups.rb`

`scope = Group.where("owner_id = ?", current_user.id).scoped`

The `.scoped` method makes your array an activerecord object that can have further methods applied like paging, ordering and such.

If you want to get the group with items of the current_user perhaps you could use,

`Group.joins(:items).where("owner_id = ?", current_user.id)`

instead?

Comment: In fact for the admin/items.rb, I need the items within the groups belonging to the user. I use the map function to get the items from the groups. I tried to had a scoped there but that did not work.